# Group by a data frame and find group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

We have to group it by given column name(list of column names). After that, you should print data of the group with a specified column value(values).  The input will contain two lines. 
First-line will have a list of columns
second will have a list of values. 
The output should have the first five rows of the corresponding group.

i need to use print command to print the dataframe.

Sample input:

```
['Pclass','Age']
[3,13]
```

output:

```
        PassengerId  Pclass               Name           Sex   Age  
154         1046       3   Asplund, Master. Filip Oscar  male  13.0 
392         1284       3  Abbott, Master. Eugene Joseph  male  13.0
```

Comment: Hi Manish. Please provide more input like what does your dataframe look like now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [`GroupBy.get_group`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.get_group.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Pclass': np.random.choice(range(10), 200),
                   'Age': np.random.choice(range(20), 200),
                   'Val': np.random.normal(0, 1, 200)}
                  )
cols = ['Pclass','Age']
keys = [3, 13]

df.groupby(cols).get_group(tuple(keys))
#     Pclass  Age       Val
#139       3   13  1.237816
#197       3   13 -1.035242
```

---

If you want to deal with an arbitrary list that might have a single element the above will break, because we need to provide a tuple only when there are multiple keys.

```
def get_grp(df, cols, keys):
    if len(keys) > 1:
        keys = tuple(keys)
    else:
        keys = keys[0]
    
    return df.groupby(cols).get_group(keys)

get_grp(df, cols, keys)  # Same output as above
```

Comment: Thanks ALollz. i have on more query on top of this.
If i have to group it by all non-numeric columns(numeric columns would be float and int) and print the resulting dataframe aggregated by averages. how can i achieve this?

Comment: With the above you could just call `.mean()` after you `get_group`. On the other hand, if you wanted to do the calculation for all of the groups, you'd `GroupBy.mean()` and then this creates a MultiIndex with your columns, which you could then access your group with `.loc`, so something like `df.groupby(cols).mean().loc[tuple(keys)]`

Comment: An easy way to get the different types of columns is with `select_dtypes`. So your numeric columns would be `num_cols = df.head().select_dtypes(np.number).columns.tolist()` and then `oth_cols = df.columns.difference(num_cols).tolist()` are all non-numeric columns.

Comment: Thanks will try it out